# After refreshing a collection, how to get the models that are changed?

Tags: backbone.js

After I refresh a Collection, is there a way to know if the collection has changed and if so, to retrieve the individual models that are new, modified, or deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

I recomend re-reading the documentation [refresh](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-refresh).  Refresh will remove ALL models from a collection, and then load only those models which you pass into it.

Therefore to answer your questions:

1. The collection will always be changed
2. All models are essentially fresh, but you'd have to look at their id's to see if they are `new` or not.
3. You can't tell which have been deleted - unless you save a copy of the collection before, and do a pair by pair comparison.

Comment: There are ways to deal with this: build a second collection and do a compare, or overload the refresh with something more customized.  Both are Simply More Programming.